# Android RelativeLayout and button problem

Tags: android, xml, button, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have a layout working as a I would like in portrait mode.  However it does not display as I would like on landscape mode:

[Portrait mode](http://www.bexville.com/stack1.png)

[Landscape mode](http://www.bexville.com/stack2.png)

Here is an outline of the .xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView />
        <TextView />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView />

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView />
                <TextView />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical">
                <Spinner />
                <Spinner />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the actual .xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/departure_block"
        android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="40px">

        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="17sp"
            android:text="You are departing from " />

        <TextView android:id="@+id/editTextDepartureStation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="" android:layout_weight="2" android:textSize="17sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/info_block" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="17sp"
        android:layout_below="@id/departure_block" android:text="Please select remaining journey details: "
        android:layout_marginTop="40px" />

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_below="@id/info_block"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <!-- Labels and widgets -->
        <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20px">

            <!-- Labels -->
            <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2" android:paddingBottom="10px">

                <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="70px" android:text="@string/destinationStation"
                    android:layout_weight="2" android:paddingTop="15px"
                    android:textSize="17sp" />

                <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="70px" android:text="@string/numTickets"
                    android:layout_weight="2" android:paddingTop="15px"
                    android:textSize="17sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <!-- End labels -->

            <!-- Widgets -->
            <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <Spinner android:id="@+id/spinnerDestinationStation"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:prompt="@string/destination_prompt" android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="17sp" />


                <Spinner android:id="@+id/spinnerNumTickets"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:prompt="@string/numTickets_prompt" android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="17sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <!-- End widgets -->

        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- End labels and widgets -->

    </LinearLayout>


    <Button android:id="@+id/buttonPurchase" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Purchase ticket"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:textSize="17sp" android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" android:shadowColor="#000000"
        android:shadowRadius="1.5" android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:shadowDx="1"
        android:shadowDy="1" android:layout_margin="10px" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

I understand why the button is appearing on top of the spinners (it is correctly align to the bottom of the parent RelativeLayout), but I just can't create the xml which would stop the overlap problem.

I would like any scrolling or ScrollView to encapsulate the button. It is not a problem if the button appears off the bottom of the display - as long as it can be accessed by scrolling. This is what I struggled to achieve.

Can anyone help?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your layout is too big for the screen, so you'll have to wrap the `info_block` in a `ScrollView`, and align that to the top, as well as its bottom to the top of the button.

This means you'll have to define the Button *before* the info_block, so that you can align the info_block's bottom to the button's top.

To clarify, the problem is your info_block's bottom edge is not bound to anything, so draw the button and you will have an edge to lay against. You should always draw the fixed elements in a relative layout first to give position for the unbound elements to edge against.

Comment: you don't need to place it on a ScrollView as a relativelayout can be made to scroll

Comment: He wants the button to be fixed at bottom as part of the layout. How would you scroll the info_block in this situation then?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your best option would be to make the Relative Layout scroll-able I believe it's called? That way a user can use their finger to move the whole layout up and down.

Answer (score 0):

I will have to check tomorrow, but fillViewport seems to be the ScrollView attribute I want. Explained in: [ScrollView’s handy trick](http://www.curious-creature.org/2010/08/15/scrollviews-handy-trick/).

Edited to add this did resolve my issue. The two important things are:

1. To use fillViewport="true" in the ScrollView, this ensures the child element expands to fill the display.  This alone won't be enough, the next thing to ensure:
2. The last element **before** the Button has android:layout_weight="1.0" to ensure it fills the space created by the ScrollView having fillViewport="true".